# Linux/C++: getting user's directory without leaks

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks

What am I doing wrongly that there are memory leaks in the following code which simply tries to read the home directory of the user?

```
static std::string getHomeDir()
{
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    std::string res( pw->pw_dir);
    endpwent();
    return res;
}
```

valgrind complains:

```
==32757== 160 (40 direct, 120 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 42 of 48
==32757==    at 0x402BB7A: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==32757==    by 0x456E84E: nss_parse_service_list (nsswitch.c:678)
==32757==    by 0x456EFC9: __nss_database_lookup (nsswitch.c:175)
==32757==    by 0x4A8E168: ???
==32757==    by 0x4A8FB5C: ???
==32757==    by 0x4525FA6: getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.1.2 (getXXbyYY_r.c:256)
==32757==    by 0x45258ED: getpwuid (getXXbyYY.c:117)
==32757==    by 0x805AD56: getHomeDir() (ConfigReader.cpp:73)
```

(also, as a sidenote: `man getpwuid` show an example program, that also leaks the same amount of memory...)

(and for those who want to compare with their linuxes:

`uname -a` gives `Linux reference 3.5.0-47-generic #71-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 23:59:30 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux` ... basically Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: what headers are you including? I tried: `unistd.h` and `pwd.h` and got no leaks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2314):

> nss_parse_service_list leaks a tiny amount of memory

It is considered resolved as "WONTFIX", with a comment stating that "the memory is allocated once to hold global state, and isn't normally freed."

Comment: Not only that, it can leak some amount of memory every time it is called.  http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~islene/2s2008-mo806/libc/nss/nsswitch.c you can see in nss_parse_service_list that malloc() is called, and when it does not return null, sometimes the result is leaked by early return statements.  This is not very good.

Comment: Strange ...  After seeing the comments on the bug page it says "subsequent calls do not cause it to allocate any more memory". But for me every time I run the application it complains about this ...

Comment: @JohnZwinck exactly my observation too.

Comment: @fritzone: what they mean by that is that calling the function multiple times in one process will not leak additional memory.  I'm not convinced that's 100% true (see my comment above), but oh well.

Comment: @fritzone By "subsequent calls" they mean "subsequent calls within the same program". When you restart the application, the global state is gone, so the leak is going to re-appear. If you call this in a loop say, 100 times, you should see only one leak report.

Comment: @fritzone The implication is that it is "subsequent calls" in the same process.  When your process ends, all of the memory is released back to the OS.

Comment: Yes, misunderstood the phrase! Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the `getpwuid` function or some other libc functions allocate some internal buffers that are never freed. You can't do much about it, just don't worry about this.

Contrary to dasblinkenlight's answer, this is **not a bug,** as one of the commenters to that report points out:

> First of all, this is no leak. The memory is allocated once to hold global state. It's normally not freed. But for memory debuggers it is.